# Postgresql query between 2 tables

Tags: postgresql, join

There are 3 fields in TABLE_A (id1,id2,value), 2 fields in TABLE_B(id,name). I want to get the name instead of id1/id2 according to id=id1/id=di2

```
select id1,id2,value from TABLE_A;
select name from TABLE_B where id=id1;
select name from TABLE_B where id=id2;
```

How to combine these three statements into one, and return the results like following:

```
name(id1) | name(id2) | value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select c.name, b.name, a.value from TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b, TABLE_B c
where b.id = a.id1 and c.id = a.id2
```